# Laravel 5.0: Implementation of Notification System(Facebook, Twitter and stackoverflow)

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, twitter

I am an absolute beginner of Laravel and web development.
I would like add a notification system similar to one on Facebook, Twitter and stackoveflow.
However, I do not have any idea where to start. 
I would like to ask a few questions to anyone who is familiar about how to set the system.

**1st question:**

I would like to know a method/function that tells me how many times a method/function is called. In my case, I would like to have the number of the function 'store' being called in the header.blade.php file.

Just like facebook, twitter, and stackoverflow tell you that your friends and followers put comments on your photo or tweet or that someone put answers on your question, and then the number shows up on the notification icon, I would like to the number of the function 'store' that has been called for a certain period of time.

**ReasonsController.php**

```
public function store(CreateReasonRequest $request, $course_id){

    $reason = new Reason($request->all());
    $reason->course_id = $course_id;
    \Auth::user()->reasons()->save($reason);
    return redirect('student/home');
}
```

**Header.blade.php**

```
<a id="dLabel" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" data-target="#" href="/page.html">
     <span class = "badge" id = "number">
         <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-bell">
            {{-- the number of the function 'store' being called comes here--}}
          </i>
     </span>
 </a>
```

**2nd question:**

When the user clicks the icon on facebook and twitter, the number on the icon disappears as you can imagine. How am I supposed to do that? What language should I use, javascript? jquery? css?

English is not my first language, so please leave your comments if this post does not make sense.
ANY ADVICE WOULD BE APPRECIATED!! THANKS IN ADVANCE!

Answer (score 1):

### 1st question:

Every time `store()` is called, you save a new `Reason` to database and associate it with the user right? To show the number of reasons, you just have to figure out how many records (in the table `reasons`) there are associated with the logged in user. Judging from the code above, you've already set up the `reasons` relationship in your User model, getting the total number of rows is as easy as calling `\Auth::user()->reasons()->count();`.

Put this code in your Header.blade.php

```
   @if (Auth::guest())
      Please login first.
   @else
     {{ Auth::user()->reasons()->count() }}
   @endif
```

### 2nd question:

Suppose you have a `notifications` table, you may add a `unread` boolean to the schema to know whether or not the user has read the notification. When you need the count of unread notifications, you write

```
Auth::user()->notifications()->where("unread",true)->count()
```

When you click on the icon, an `AJAX request` is sent to the server to fetch all the unread messages. JavaScript is used to clear the notification count. And at the same time, the server sets the `unread` attributes of all notifications related to that user to false. So that upon page refresh, `Auth::user()->notifications()->where("unread",true)->count()` will return 0.

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice! Kevin! I have a question about your answer, though. How am I supposed to know if the notifications are read or not by the user? and change the key of "unread" to true to false?

Comment: It's an extra attribute you add to the schema of notifications table, with default value set to true. When the user fetches and reads the notification, you set that attribute to false.

Comment: You change this attribute in the handler of the AJAX request (the one I mentioned before)